# Exim - route non-local emails to remote host

Tags: email, centos

We have Exim (within a cPanel environment, but we're considering stripping out the cPanel dependency) set up as an outbound mailserver for our infrastructure, but also have G Suite (Google Workspace now, I think) set up for most other emails. Let's use example.com as our domain.

- Email sent to noreply@example.com and dmarcprocessor@example.com are sent to our Exim through a custom routing rule in Google Workspace
- Since noreply and dmarcprocessor are local accounts, we have it set to local delivery for example.com.
- All email sent to users, as well as internal stuff like Jira, is sent through Exim.

The issue here is that if we want to send email to an @example.com address, it doesn't work because Exim tries local delivery and then fails out. Email to anywhere else works fine.

How can we get Exim to try local delivery first, and then try remote delivery?

Comment: Have a look at [Configure exim to use remote smtp with authentication - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/362907/configure-exim-to-use-remote-smtp-with-authentication)